# 'PyPardisoError: The Pardiso solver failed with error code -3. See Pardiso documentation for details'. How to solve it?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, brightway, pardiso

PyPardisoError: The Pardiso solver failed with error code -3. See Pardiso documentation for details.

I was working on Jupyter Notebook and I found this error. What does it mean and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error -3 is a matrix reordering problem. Reordering (moving around rows or columns to make the math easier) should not normally cause issues; please make sure you have a square, non-singular matrix.

If you can't figure it out, you can post the specific system you are working on to the Brightway mailing list or give a link here.

EDIT: The problem was instead a [compatibility problem with `intel-openmp` and `mkl`](https://github.com/haasad/PyPardisoProject/issues/36). The solution given in the Github issue is to force an older version of `intel-openmp`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge intel-openmp=2021.4
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved!