# Temporal datasets calculation with "PyPardisoError: The Pardiso solver failed with error code -4" error

Tags: brightway, temporal-database

I try to run dynamic life cycle assessment on Temporalis. After I constructed the temporal database, and ran `tempo.graph_technosphere()` and `timel_st=dlca_st.calculate()`, both came out the "PyPardisoError: The Pardiso solver failed with error code -4." I check the Pardiso manual document and -4 shows "Zero pivot, numerical fact. or iterative refinement problem." I think it might be the zero pivot problem. But I am not sure. How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [library incompatibility problem](https://github.com/haasad/PyPardisoProject/issues/36#issuecomment-1009327877). See the link for potential workarounds before the upstream fixes land.

Comment: Thank you! Right now I don't have error -4 problem. But it raises PyPardisoError error code -3. I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70665142/pypardisoerror-the-pardiso-solver-failed-with-error-code-3-see-pardiso-docum?rq=1), and I found my database is square but singular. How to change the database to non-singular?

Comment: If you are sure your matrix is singular, then I guess you are missing a production exchange for some activity. But according to the link you posted, I venture to guess that this is still the MKL compatibility problem - have you downgraded MKL?

Comment: I have downgraded MKL. But I think I miss production exchanges for two activities since I used `technosphere_matrix` and found two rows were all zero. How can I find out which product or activity has no amount?

Comment: I figured out where I did wrong! Thank you, Dr. Mutel!